# How to use both map and reduce in same function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I would like to display the value 122 of amount but I don't know how to do that.

I have this value

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    productM: [
      {
        product: {
          productId: 1222,
          price: {
            currency: 'EUR',
            amount: 122,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    label: 'corner-1',
    sourceId: 23333,
  },
]
```

I tried this function but it's not working and I don't know how to do that

```
function getTotalPrice(products) {
  const arr = products.map((product) =>
    product.productM.map((p) => p.price.amount)
  );
  return arr.reduce(
    (accumulator, product) => accumulator + product,
    0
  );
}
```

If anyone can help, many thanks

Comment: The elements in `product.productM` do not have a `price` property. They only have a `product` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map` and `reduce`. You can use `reduce` only.

Since `products` is nested one more level, you can use `reduce` twice to get it done.

Try like this.

```
function getTotalPrice(products) {
    return products.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return (
            prev +
            curr.productM.reduce((innerPrev, innerCurr) => {
                return innerPrev + innerCurr.product.price.amount;
            }, 0)
        );
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work, you assumed that `p` was product but in reality `p` is the whole object, try this:

```js
function getTotalPrice(products) {
  const arr = products.map((product) =>
    product.productM.reduce(
      (total, { product }) => total + product.price.amount,
      0
    )
  );
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, product) => accumulator + product, 0);
}
```

ProductM is an array so I changed it from map to a reduce, to sum all the productsM prices in it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to map anything, you can reduce directly over the original array:

```js
function getTotalPrice(products) {
  return products.reduce((acc, p) => acc + p.productM.product.price.amount, 0);
}
```